# Nintex for O365: XPath query is invalid. Expression must evaluate to a node-set

Tags: xml, xpath, nintex-workflow

I'm having an Infopath form which is having sections numbered from 0 to 14. They are being filled based on some rules. I'd like to use a "Query XML" action to get only those having values in nodes  (where {n} is the next number from 0 to 14). I'm then using the following XPath query:

```
//my:Approvals/*[starts-with(name(), 'my:Approve')][*[starts-with(name(), 'my:ID') and text() >= 0]]
```

When I'm testing the query using the http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath tester it returns me 3 nodes.
However when I execute my workflow processing the actions logs error message:

*XPath query is invalid. Expression must evaluate to a node-set..*

I have no idea how to debug what this action is returning or what am I doing wrong, when on the other hand XPath tester tells me everything should be correct...

I highly appreciate any help

Best regards,
Tomasz

Comment: does it make a difference if you try `//*[name() = 'my:Approvals']/*[starts-with(name(), 'my:Approve')][*[starts-with(name(), 'my:ID') and text() >= 0]]` ?

Comment: @KeithHall it doesn't. In fact this construction returns 0 nodes when tested using xpathtester ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that everything was correct. Well, the better query is:

```
//my:Approvals/*[starts-with(name(), 'my:Approve')][*[starts-with(name(), 'my:ID') and text()[number()>=‍0]]]
```

So the one, that coverts node value into a number, but in the end the problem was, that the tested value was being passed as a variable and.. it turned out it was empty at the time of comparison.

So my bad, thanks for your time trying figuring out what is wrong ;)

Regards,
Tomasz